# Is this really Async ? IEnumerable<T> Extension

Tags: c#, asynchronous, collections

```
public static async Task<T> FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> obj) where T : class
{
    var first = await Task.WhenAny(obj);

    return first?.Result?.FirstOrDefault() ?? null;
}
```

Here are the 2 others methods to show the complete

***Main Method*** (in this case will return only item in the collection or a collection empty)

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> fetchRecordsAsync(SqlCommand SqlCommand, bool isSingleRecord)
{..some code...}
```

Here is the caller that will get the collection and pass only T:

```
protected async Task<T> GetSingleRecord(SqlCommand SqlCommand)
{
    return await fetchRecordsAsync(SqlCommand, true).FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync();
}
```

Is this the correct way to work with async extentions of IEnumerable or it will be doing a sync?

Do I really need create another task (first)?

Comment: it will not continue until the task is complete.

Comment: You mean *this IEnumerable<Task<T>> obj* for the argument?

Comment: how would you call this method? how you pass `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`?

Comment: You are mixing async and sync code. which is bad

Comment: Why don't you simply do `return (await obj)?.FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: The *?? null* is redundant

Comment: @Nkosi Thats the point... I know that is not 100% async, how can I make real async?

Comment: @Nkosi He's not, actually.  He's only ever calling `Result` on a completed `Task`, so it will never synchronously block.

Comment: @Servy you are correct. makes sense now after reviewing it more closely. that was my misunderstanding. thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this really Async ?

Yes it is. `await Task.WhenAny` will return the first task that completes. Using `.Result` on such task (a completed one) will not cause a synchronous wait.

BTW, you don't need to use `Task.WhenAny`, your method can be simplified like this:

```
public static async Task<T> FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync<T>(
    this Task<IEnumerable<T>> obj) where T : class
{
    var result = await obj;

    return result?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @Jonesopolis, "A task that represents the completion of one of the supplied tasks" means an incomplete task (unless one input task is already completed). It is a task the will complete when any of the input tasks completes.

Comment: There wouldn't be an incomplete task because OP is only passing one task into `WhenAny()`. But it's true that it's nonsensical to use `WhenAny()` here.

Comment: @JLRishe, there is a very small chance that the async database access is complete before the call to `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sure, but then it's complete, and so safe to call `Result` on it.  The point is that you know, with 100% certainty, that the task has completed (either successfully or otherwise), and so `Result` will not perform a blocking wait.  It *cannot* return an incomplete task.

Comment: @Servy, you are right. I made a mistake. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

It will be doing all of its work asynchronously, although there is a lot there that's unnecessary (although not harmful, other than a very small additional overhead).

There's no point in calling `WhenAny` when you're only passing in one task.  You might as well just await the task itself; it does the same thing.

Writing `?? null` is pointless.  If the value is `null` make it `null`.  It was already `null`, so you can just leave it.

You also aren't ever passing a null `Task` to `FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync`, and you really shouldn't either.  You also likely shouldn't be producing a `null` `IEnumerable` for the result.  If there are no items you should really have an *empty* sequence.

There's also no reason to restrict the method to only work for sequences of classes.  If someone wants to use a value type there's no real reason to stop them.

It also makes sense to adjust the name of the method, so that its name reflects what it's actually doing.

So now all of this can just boil down to:

```
public static async Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
{    
    return (await task).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Your other method also has no reason to be `async`, since you're never doing anything with the awaited value besides re-wrapping it in a `Task` and returning it.  Just return the `Task` that you have:

```
protected Task<T> GetSingleRecordAsync(SqlCommand SqlCommand)
{
    return fetchRecordsAsync(SqlCommand, true)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```